# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource : Mean stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have installed cors & body parser. This is my `authSrvice.js` file

```
resetemail(emailid) {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/femail',emailid,{headers:headers})
   .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

This is from routes file

```
const User = require('../models/user');
router.post('/femail',(req,res,next) => {
    const emailid = req.email.body;
    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
      if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }
    else {
      return res.json({success: true, msg: 'success'});
    }
    });
  });
```

In chrome console it's showing an error as

> Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/femail: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
>   Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   http://localhost:3000/api/femail with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

In my cmd is showing as

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at createStrictSyntaxError (E:\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
>       at parse (E:\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>       at E:\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>       at invokeCallback (E:\project-1\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>       at done (E:\project-1\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\project-1\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>       at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

This is my `server.js`

```
    const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session')
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var async = require('async');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// Connect To Database
mongoose.connect(config.database);
// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to database '+config.database);
});

// On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Database error: '+err);
});

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
//app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/api',users);
// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.send('Invalid endpoint');
});

// Body Parser Middleware


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });

app.use(session({ secret: 'this is a cat' }));  
app.use(cookieParser());
// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use('/users', users);



app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log("Server started on port:", port); 
});
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> The response had HTTP status code 400.

Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers won't fix the problem if the server is throwing an error.

You need to figure out why the error is being thrown.

Most likely this is because, by POSTing JSON, you are triggering a preflight options request that the server is not equipped to handle.

Replace your homegrown CORS middleware with [this standard module](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) which supports preflight OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 1):

`app.use(cors());` should come before all other middlewares.